# How did Count Otto von Doom's assassin kill Queen Elizabeth I?

Tags: marvel, dr-doom, marvel-1602

In *[Marvel 1602](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_1602)* #3, Count Otto von Doom sends three assassins after key people in England. The implication is that the third and final one arrived in the court of Queen Elizabeth I as an envoy from Latveria, who presents a musical contraption designed by von Doom himself. In the last scene where we see him, he kisses the Queen's hand.

[image]

Then a few panels later, we see Queen apparently having had a violent death with the musical contraption standing ominously.

[image]

I don't understand this panel; how did Queen Elizabeth I die? My first though is that, since it appears she died violently, the contraption shot her. But I don't see an arrow or even a wound and the angle of the dead Queen compared to the contraption's trumpet seems all wrong. My next thought was poison of some sort from the envoy kissing her finger, but that doesn't seem to match with the final scene.

How did Count Otto von Doom's third assassin kill Queen Elizabeth I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [issue #04](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_1602_Vol_1_4) we learn that the "contraption" Doom sent emitted a poison gas which killed the Queen. Doom mentions dropping a "pill" into Aqua Regia (a mixture of nitric acid and hydrochloric acid). If this pill contained potassium cyanide, for example, it would have created deadly hydrogen cyanide gas.

[image]